# Why I cannot push iOS app to App Store after being added to a team?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have been added to the company account as an App Manager user.

After that I created a new bundle ID and enabled Push Notifications. Push Notifications are not in the code now, but we may use them later.

The next step was creating an app on iTunes and using this bundle ID.

After that I chose my name as the provisioning profile in XCode, crated archive and started uploading process. I was offered to choose a profile and I picked profile with my name.

**Should I be seeing my name here (like Jim Doe) or I should see and pick a profile looking like My Client Company Team?**

The upload breaks with error

`ERROR ITMS-90159: "Invalid provisioning profile. This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID XXX."`

There is a change that I wrongly navigated my client to add me to his profile. If I skipped some step please let me know.

Comment: http://blog.hoachuck.biz/blog/2012/12/04/use-a-provisioning-profile-associated-with-team-id/ this may helpful

Comment: In project->Targets , General Tab, did you checked Automatically code signing and selected the team(not your JohnDoe account) from the dropdown list?

Comment: @Picci That is weird as I do not see the team (client account) I was added to? I can see other teams but not this one.

Comment: @MahipalSingh The project did not exist before. I created it on my machine so I am the only person who has ever worked in this iTunes project.

Comment: then please clean your derived data and then check both "project and target" --> Build settings --> Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: You have to remove old provisioning profile and create new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an answer for all those that have the same issue.

Apple completely separates Apple Developer portal from iTunesConnect. A client **must invite you to both Apple Developer and iTunesConnect**!

iTunesConnect will allow you to create apps and sort all details that will appear on the App Store. While Apple Developer is **bound to development and XCode looks at its permissions when you try to pull team provisioning profiles**.

In my case, once I have been added to client's Apple Developer, I was able to see his team and push build to iTunesConnect.